# Solr faceted search within a column

Tags: solr

I need to a faceted search on a particular column and drill down within its results.

Here is my schema.

```
State ZipCode PersonName
CA    12345   Tom
CA    12345   Mike
CA    23458   John
CA    23458   Lucy
```

I tried writing a facet query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/query?facet=on&facet.field=State and it facets only based on State.
```

How do I include Zip code within it, so that I can drill down based on State & Zip code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this two ways, depending on what you want.

If you just want to include a ZipCode facet as well, in addition to the State facet, [add another `facet.field` parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.field): `&facet.field=ZipCode`. That way you'll get facets for both fields in your response. The facets will be modified depending on your query results and filter queries, so if the user selects a State first, the fq= will make the ZipCode facet only return facet values within that state. You might also want to look at [Tagging and excluding filters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams), if you want to show a count of all States, regardless of one being chosen at the moment.

Another option is to use [`facet.pivot`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting) to get a two-dimensional table with facet values; for each state, get the count of the zipcodes in that state. `&facet.pivot=State,ZipCode`.